# Tensorflow - Detecting multiple objects on trained softmax classification model

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, softmax

I have used the standard SVHN cropped digits dataset to generate a model that classifies into the 10 possible digits, with accuracy of 89.89% on the testing set. Moving on, I would like to detect multiple digits on an image. (e.g. the numbers on a car registration plate) How would I go about doing this? Would I need to retrain my model to detect multiple images?

```
#conv1
W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,32,32,1])
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

#conv2
W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

#Densely
W_fc1 = weight_variable([8 * 8 * 64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 8*8*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

#Dropout
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

#Readout
W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])
y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2

#Train
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y_conv))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for i in range(40000):
  batch = shvn_data.nextbatch(100)
  if i%100 == 0:
    train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
        x:batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
    print("step %d, training accuracy %f"%(i, train_accuracy))
  train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})
```

My code was modified from here: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros. My code can be found here: https://github.com/limwenyao/ComputerVision/blob/testing/CNN_MNIST.py#L216

Comment: add your code here, do not make us follow external links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would wrap a striding system around your net. So you take your image with the car plates and cut it down into many smaller images, then run your digit detection on each of the smaller images and record the found digits and at the end put them together and voilà your plate number.

This process of cutting the license plate image into smaller images usually is a trained net as well. So you would have two nets:

- One learns to cut well
- The other learns to read ONE digit from each cut subimage